# run_web.sh not found even though it's there in dir?

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I just installed Docker, after setting up few things like Python, Django, etc., I got an error before my web server gets running.

To get web server running I have written a script named `run_web.sh`. It's also configured in `docker-compose.yml` that to run web server, run a command `exec run_web.sh`. When executing that command, it throws an error as below:

```
Starting portalapi_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for portalapi_web_1  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"./run_web.sh\": stat ./run_web.sh: no such file or directory"


ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"./run_web.sh\": stat ./run_web.sh: no such file or directory"

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Where `run_web.sh` file is in my root dir of the project same as `docker-compose.yml`, it is not able to find it. Don't know what is the issue.

Even when I run `exec run_web.sh` from my root dir, still gets error : `Not Found`

[image]

Comment: The correct syntax for running a file in the current directory in bash is `./run_web.sh`. There should not be any `exec` involved in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ENTRYPOINT` is the default one ( `/bin/sh -c`), which you can check with a `docker image inspect <yourImage>`, then try simply as a `CMD`:

```
/full/path/of/run_web.sh
```

That way, you reference directly what you want to launch.